# Can't create a DEM in R language

Tags: r

If anyone use the package topmodel in R, it need an archive like name.dem which contain a matrix of elevation data, how i can to create if in an example given the name of archive is huagrahuma.dem.RData I import with read.table and save with extension dem (not work), try to save with extension RData (not work) What can i do Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not an archive. The example here http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=guides:tutorials:hydrological_data_analysis:dta uses the `data` function to put the object `huagrahuma.dem` into your workspace. If you do:

```
image(huagrahuma.dem)
```

you'll see an elevation map.

The object is just a matrix of heights. Create it and call it what you like, for example, a completely random DEM:

```
 randomElev = matrix(100*runif(120*120),120,120)
```

would create a 120x120 DEM of random heights between 0 and 100.

Comment: my problem is that i need a specific real DEM, and the format of this force me to import data to R, then how i can do this?

Comment: we can't answer that unless we know the format of your DEM data - is it a GeoTIFF? An Arc/Info Binary Grid file?

Comment: I'm sorry forget to put the format, its a GeoTIFF, thanks for your answer

Comment: Install the `raster` package, that will read it into a raster object, then you probably have to convert to a matrix for the `topmodel` function. You might want to ask another question when you get that far.